# How to use Office365 with Roaming Profiles, without require user to enter credentials/activate on every pc?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-365, user-profile, roaming-profile

What are we missing? We try to use Office365 and roaming profiles. The problem is that applications prompt the user to login (or activate) when they roam to another pc.

[image]

I have read: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/activation/shared-computer-activation#general

We created this policy:

[image]

We verified that the License files are in the user-profile: `%appdata%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Licensing`

We also verified that Office is in Shared Computer Activation mode:

[image]

I'm testing like this:

1. Log an to a pc (Windows 11, up-to-date)
2. Setup Outlook, Word, Teams and OneDrive (Click-to-to-Run, up-to-date)
3. Log off
4. Delete local profile (System > Advanced > Profiles)
5. Logon again
6. Verify Office is still working without prompts for credentials.

We can't get this to work. When you start Outlook, Word or another Office-app, it stills prompts the user to login to Office365.

We noticed that the Office365 School or Work-account is not listed in Settings > Accounts after logging in again (so when the local profile was deleted). It's not saved in the user profile.

To be clear: roaming profiles itself works fine. When the user logs into Office365, his or her mail is working fine too. All other settings are roaming, the problem is just the authentication.

Comment: Logon to what? If you can't provide at least that this isn't going to get very far. Really it sounds like you could take a generic, vanilla computer with nothing installed, install Office, and the user will be prompted to logon and Office does not work regardless of who the user is providing their credentials to.

Comment: @GregAskew, thank you for taking the time to respond. When roaming profiles are used, users should not have to login to Office365 each time they start Outlook, Word or another Office-app on another pc. Their license should roam with them. This is clearly stated by Microsoft. However, we can't get it to work. Do you think my question isn't making this problem clear? Or do you think me test is not correct?

Comment: There are multiple "things" that could be authenticated. Providing the "thing" that they are authenticating to would save further wheel spinning.

Comment: I added a screenshot. It is just the Office365 login prompt.  I don't know any other thing that can be authenticated.

Comment: Specifically, I believe you are looking for "Windows roaming credential manager for username and password credentials". For part of it. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46757663/roaming-user-profiles-password-file-location https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/certs-on-wheels-understanding-credential-roaming/ba-p/395897

Comment: I checked that, but it's not saved in Windows Credential Manager. But reading further I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/overview-shared-computer-activation#how-shared-computer-activation-works-for-microsoft-365-apps 

"To determine whether the user is licensed to use Microsoft 365 Apps, the Office Licensing Service has to know the user's account for Office 365. In some cases, Microsoft 365 Apps prompts the user to provide the information. For example, the user might see the Activate Office dialog box."

I think it's by design.

Comment: It also says: "If your environment is configured to synchronize Office 365 (Azure Active Directory) and local Active Directory (AD) accounts, then the user most likely won't see any prompts."

Answer (score 0):

**I think it's not working as we expected.** I've read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployOffice/overview-shared-computer-activation

[image]

Because of the line..

> There's a different licensing token for each computer that the user signs in.

...**I expect that you cannot roam the license-files as we tried**. You can, but they don't work on the other pc. Still: does this mean that it's not possible to have Office365 roam with a user without the O365 login prompts?

Our scenario is listed on that same article:

> Here are some examples of supported scenarios:
> Fifteen nurses at a hospital use Office on 10 different computers throughout the day.